# how to save a file to upper level folder?

Tags: c#, webforms, directory

the structure of folders in server look like this:

- www.example.com

  - images
  - web file

    - here all the files for web
    - index.html
    - example.html

My code is inside web file folder. To save files inside the web file i can use`server.MapPath("~\\folder")`. 
 But how to save file to images folder which is located in upper level and same lvl as web file under www.example.com?

New learner, please guide..

Comment: I think he means that the folder is above the root...

Comment: Add the folder path in your web.config and save the file in that path. it is simple.

Comment: @codingkiwi.com yes, i'm trying to save file to folder above the application root folder.

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
server.MapPath("~/images/myfile.jpg");
```

Comment: that will only save file to `web file` directory.

Comment: images folder and web file folder is at the same level. the code for saving file is inside web file folder. so if using this code `server.mappath("~\\myfile.jpg");`, it only can save file within web file folder.

Comment: specifying the images folder as a virtual directory in your iis so for code it will behave like it is in the web file folder, but fysicly it will be in the structure you have it now. see http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc771804(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The MapPath method maps a specified path to a physical path.

this is some prectice for you

```
    <%
response.write(Server.MapPath("test.asp") & "<br />")
response.write(Server.MapPath("script/test.asp") & "<br />")
response.write(Server.MapPath("/script/test.asp") & "<br />")
response.write(Server.MapPath("\script") & "<br />")
response.write(Server.MapPath("/") & "<br />")
response.write(Server.MapPath("\") & "<br />")
%>

Output:

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script\test.asp
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script\script\test.asp
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script\test.asp
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script
c:\inetpub\wwwroot
c:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

If you want to use relative path to ur www or root directory

```
 response.write(Server.MapPath("../"))
```

OR

```
 response.write(Server.MapPath("..\"))
```

Comment: i tried it, but can save only inside application folder. i'm trying to save file above the application root. `Server.MapPath("..\")` or `(Server.MapPath("../")` giving me an error **Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.**